# Is there a way to implement the same behaviour of the new operator calling default constructors?

Tags: c++, windows, dynamic-memory-allocation, new-operator, default-constructor

I want to implement my own heap allocation function to do the same as the C++ new operator when it comes to allocating elements of a class type. My allocation function (for Windows) does not use the new operator or the standard library, but only [HeapAlloc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/heapapi/nf-heapapi-heapalloc). So my problem is when allocating elements of a class type :

```
// Allocation function definition.
template <typename Type>
Type* Alloc(int Count) {
  return reinterpret_cast<Type*>(HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, sizeof(Type) * Count));
}

// Allocation function use.
Alloc<Class>(5);
```

The function allocates 5 `Class`, which is a simple class with a single default constructor. The constructor does not get called, and I can see why. The only thing I do is allocate some memory and `reinterpret_cast` it.

Where I get confused though, is with the new operator :

```
new Class[5];
```

The default constructor gets called! The new operator is in the end (on Windows of course) also calling `HeapAlloc`. The function does some other stuff too, but none of it seems to really have an impact on the final result.

How can `new` call the constructors of each element it allocates, and can I do the same? Or is this just some built-in feature (even though it's part of the standard library)?

Comment: Have a look at placement new.

Comment: You can override the `new` operator and you should use placement `new` to call the constructors after allocating the space.

Comment: So called _`new` expressions_ (`new int[5]`) call `operator new` (similar to `malloc`) _and_ the objects constructor. You can use _placement `new` expressions_ or `std::construct_at` from C++20 to call the constructors manually.

Comment: You can do a combination of HeapAlloc and what std::bit_cast does. C++23 also has std::start_lifetime_as

Comment: Also, if the allocator should be used for a particular type and its subclasses only, you can use member `operator new(std::size_t)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So called *`new` expressions* (`new int[5]`) call `operator new` (similar to `malloc`) *and* the objects' constructor. You can use *placement `new` expressions* or `std::construct_at` from C++20 to call the constructors manually. Your code could end up looking like this:

```
// Raw memory allocation function
void* AllocBytes(size_t size, size_t align) {
    void* p = HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, align);
    assert(reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(p) % align == 0 && 
           "Invalid alignment");
    return p;
}

// Raw memory deallocation function
void DeallocBytes(void* p, size_t size, size_t align) {
    // Use Windows API to deallocate memory
}

// Allocation AND construction function 
template <typename Type>
Type* Alloc(size_t Count) {
    // Allocate memory for 'Count' elements
    Type* array = reinterpret_cast<Type*>(AllocBytes(Count * sizeof(Type), alignof(Type)));
    // Construct 'Count' elements in the memory buffer
    for (size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        std::construct_at(&array[i]); // From <memory> in C++20

        // _Or_ a placement new expression
        ::new (&array[i]) Type();
    }
    return array;
}

// Destruction AND deallocation function 
template <typename Type>
void Dealloc(Type* p, size_t Count) {
    // Destroy 'Count' elements in the memory buffer
    for (size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        std::destroy_at(&array[i]); // From <memory> in C++17

        // _Or_ explicit destructor calls
        array[i].~Type();
    }
    DeallocBytes(p, Count * sizeof(Type), alignof(Type));
}
```

Then you can use the functions like this:

```
// Allocate 5 elements
Class* p = Alloc<Class>(5);

// Deallocate 5 elements
Dealloc(p, 5);
```

Note that using `std::construct_at`/`std::destroy_at` or placement new expressions/manual destructor calls doesn't really make a difference. `std::construct_at` and `std::destroy_at` are `constexpr` and more explicit or perhaps easier to understand, but you can do it either way.

Comment: Your answer makes sense in this case, but what if `Type` in `Alloc` and `Dealloc` is not of class type? Would you have to have two different (de)allocation functions, or is there a way to implicitly differentiate?

Comment: @Justaprogrammer This already implicitly differentiates. If `Type` is `int`, then the loop with `std::construct_at` would result in a `memset(p, p + Count * sizeof(int), 0)` (which is the same behaviour as `new int[5]`) and the loop with `std::destroy_at` would be a no-op (meaning it will be optimized away completely).

Comment: Oh okay, I thought that the statement `array[i].~Type()` wouldn't compile if `Type`, for example, is `int`, but it makes sense now. Thanks for helping :)

Comment: @Justaprogrammer This is actually a weird edge case in the language. If you wrote `array[i].~int()`, even if you know the array is of type `int`, this would not compile, because `int` has no destructor. But `using Type = int; array[i].~Type();` is fine. The same applies if `Type` is a template parameter. The latter expressions are called "pseudo-destructor-calls" and they do nothing.

Comment: Note that if one wants to replicate `new[]`/`delete[]` behaviour, there should be also bookkeeping data - count how much memory (or objects) is allocated and then you do not have to pass number of elements to `Dealloc`.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I didn't do that on purpose because I think it is a terrible decision to store this meta data that the user of the allocated array needs to have anyway to do anything useful with the array. But that's just my opinion.

Comment: @chrysante I'm not criticising (I upvoted the solution earlier), but I mention that because question says they want to have a function that "does the same as `new[]`".

Comment: @Yksisarvinen It is an important point, I was just glad to have an opportunity to express my contempt for this design decision :-)